# How do you keep layouts clicks correctly referenced?

Tags: android, listview, gridview

Let me explain myself:

As you know, when you've a view which have to be inflated several times, but changing values, you use a GridView or a ListView. Those two Composite views, have some methods like `onItemClick`. This method is so useful, as it returns the **position** of the view clicked.

With this **position** you can perform some concrete tasks, like retreiving from an ArrayList, the information of that object. Here's an example:

```
ArrayList<DocumentInfo> documents;
```

And when you set a `setOnItemClickListener()` you can get the correct values:

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos, long arg3) {
        getDocumentInfoOf(pos);
    }
});
public void getDocumentInfoOf(int position){
    DocumentInfo doc = documents.get(position);
}
```

However, when you aren't using a GridView or a ListView, you're in your own. You don't have a clear way (AFAIK) to know which layout inflated is the one clicked (I mean like the previous example, the "position" value).

What I am currently doing, is the following:

```
for (int i=0; i<10;i++){
    RelativeLayout documentInflated = (RelativeLayout) this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.open_document_per_inflar, null);
    documentInflated.setContentDescription(""+i);
    documentInflated.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDocument(v);
        }
    });

    container.addView(documentInflated);
}

public void openDocument(View v){
    int idDocument = Integer.parseInt(v.getContentDescription());
    //idDocument is the view clicked
}
```

**Do you guys think this is a clear way of doing this?**

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you want to get some data from your created Relative Layout when you click on it. The best solution here is to use the method setTag(Object tag). After that you get the informatiom with the method getTag(). This method allows you to add extra information to your view. As it says in the documentation:

Tags

Unlike IDs, tags are not used to identify views. Tags are essentially an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate structure.

Also depending on your needs you can seperate every tag with a key -> value pair with the method setTag(int key, Object tag), after that you can retrieve this object with getTag(int key);

So in your case you will have

`documentInflated.setTag(i)`

in the onClick yo will then have:

```
int i = (int)v.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm not understanding your desire...

```
      @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDocument(v);
        }
```

`v` IS the view being clicked.  Your code looks like it should do what you're hoping it will do.  What are you actually seeing happen?

Comment: I might have not explained myself correctly. Let me edit my question and check it again soon please!

Comment: Ok, but isn't that in essence what you're doing? You're storing the position and then you have access to it exactly as you're doing it (you can also store/fetch it via get/setTag(). Why isn't this working as written?

Comment: My question is not "its not working, help me", the question is **Do you guys think this is a clear way of doing this?**

Comment: oh! yes. This is  perfectly rational way to do this. Your question (especially the title) didn't make clear that you're just looking for validation of an approach. It seems like you're looking for a solution.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep this question opened so I can read more answers about this same issue. Maybe someone is able to provide some google code examples to see the way they do it.